# How to set a TTL to a document in mongo using morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, indexing, morphia, database-indexes

Currently using the below code in morphia to have a ttl index on the document.

```
@Entity(value = "productDils", noClassnameStored = true)
@Indexes(
        {@Index(fields = {}, options = @IndexOptions(expireAfterSeconds = 36)),
        @Index(fields = {@Field("pid")}, options = @IndexOptions(unique = true))
}
)
public class ProductDils {}
```

But I am getting the below error. 
**Exception in thread "main" org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Could not resolve path '' against 'com.example.productdils.ProductDeils'.**

Can someone please help out?

PS: I am aware as to how this is done using mongodb java client. But my application is making use of morphia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying the field to apply the ttl to for starters.  Perhaps you just omitted the fields for brevity but you need them, of course, to define indexes against

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it now :)